# how to get the value time from TimePicker in Android

Tags: android

I simply wanna get the hour and minute from TimePicker and display it as a string, 
for example I make the timepicker 13:30, and I wanna get the hour as 13 and minute as 30 seperately.

Thats all I need.

I tried that .getHour() and getMinute() but these methods get me the current time which i dont need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing right now.  Try setting up a listener for the onTimeSet method.  It has two parameters that are exactly what you need.  For example:

Create a TimePickerDialog:

```
public void onClickSetEndTime(View v)
{
    TimePickerDialog d = new TimePickerDialog(mActivity,
            timeEndSetListener, timeEnd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            timeEnd.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);

    d.show();
}
```

Then setup the listener.  In my case it's "timeEndSetListener".

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeEndSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        // do what you need to do with the hour and minute
    }
};
```

Good luck.