# How to simply get selected time From TimePicker in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, timepicker

I want to retrieve the time from `TimePicker` in Android and store it in an appropriate variable. As I also want to save it in a SQLite database. How can I retrieve the time which is selected by the user in a easy way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the value time from TimePicker in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321468/how-to-get-the-value-time-from-timepicker-in-android)

Comment: timePicker.getCurrentMinute() * 60 + timePicker.getCurrentHour() * 60 * 60) * 1000;

Answer (score 5):

```
 timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener( new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

            @Override
                public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    date = String.valueOf(hourOfDay).toString() + ":" + String.valueOf(minute).toString();
                }

});
```

This will save the selected time from timePicker as XX:XX

Answer (score 0):

`timePicker.getCurrentHour()` and/or `timePicker.getCurrentMinute()`

Comment: which `datatype` i can use to store both of them. as i want to store them in `sqLite` database

Comment: Anything you like. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html
timePicker.getCurrentHour() returns an Integer. You can convert that to a String if you want, or just store it as an Integer.

Comment: can i store it like this                                                             `tpTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tpTime);
  int hour=tpTime.getCurrentHour();
  int min =tpTime.getCurrentMinute();
  
  String time=hour+":"+min;
  `

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, then you can try this extension I've created for TimePicker

```
fun TimePicker.getDate(): Date {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
    } else {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, currentHour)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, currentMinute)
    }
    return calendar.time
}
```